# How to have pin lock feature for certain activity or fragment in android?

Tags: android

How to have pin lock feature in app for certain activity or fragment? I searched for suitable library but didn't found. Please provide me suitable solution with example.Thank you

Comment: do you want to use device unlock pin/pattern or create it separately for your own app?

Comment: I want to create it separately for my app.

Answer (score 1):

okay, may be you should start your Activity or Fragment followed by a dialog with an editText and check for the input whether it matches the desired value.On correct input start your activity or fragment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this great library:
https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/LolliPin

> A Material design Android pin code library. Supports Fingerprint.

if it doesn't suit you [look here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/56)